# If $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E(X_t| \mathcal{F}_{t-n}) = 0 $ then $E(X_t) = 0$?

Tags: probability, limits, measure-theory, probability-theory, expectation

Suppose I have a sequence of random variables $X_t$ adapted to a filtration $\mathcal{F}$

when is it true that if
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E(X_t| \mathcal{F}_{t-n}) = 0 $ then
$E(X_t) = 0$ ?

Could I have a proof of this fact

Comment: If you read carefully the text this is taken from... you will probably note that the filtration $(\mathcal F_t)$ is indexed by all the *negative* integers (and possibly by more than them but at least by them). In such situations $\mathcal F_0$ is not the trivial sigma-algebra *at all*, for example $\mathcal F_0\supseteq\sigma(X_t;t\leqslant0)$. // And now that the context is clearer, your turn: please add to the question your tries, the similar questions you can solve, and so on.

Comment: @Did thank you for your answer and I appreciate wanting to give me my turn. Indeed you must be correct because the text states "the process is assumed to have started in the infinite past" and not at time zero.  Unfortunately the only thing that I can say is that the statement makes intuitive sense to me, because if I condition on the infinite past my information set is so small that it is like conditioning on no information at all. I suspect that the proof is measure theoretical and I am bit shaky in measure theory, I would have liked to see it anyway to see if I could have understood some.

Comment: "if I condition on the infinite past my information set is so small that it is like conditioning on no information at all" There is a whole field of research showing this is not so. Regarding your question itself, I suggest to google `Backwards martingale convergence theorem`.

Answer (score 1):

This very much depends on your definition of $\mathcal{F}_{t-n}$ for $n > t$. Usually one uses the convention $\mathcal{F}_0 = \{\emptyset, \Omega\}$ and you could always extend this to $\mathcal{F}_t = \mathcal{F}_0$ for all $t < 0$. Then, however, this statement is somewhat trivial since $E(X_t | \mathcal{F}_0) = E(X_t)$ for all $t$...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! in the case of an increasing family $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \ge 0}$  ?

Comment: @Monolite Then it is still unclear how $\lim_{n \to \infty} E(X_t | \mathcal{F}_{t-n})$ is defined since $t-n$ will be less than $0$ for some $n$...

Comment: The process $(X_t)$ starts in the infinite past is words I get from a source that utilises the statement in question. I imagine this means that the filtration is defined for all integers values? (I am struggling to find a definition of a process starting in the infinite past).

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is offtopic. For some context, see my comment to the question.

Comment: @Did Thanks for clearing that up